# como declaro un if

Tags: javascript, html

amigos necesito ayuda, tengo un menu lateral desplegable que tiene hijos implemente unos iconos de flechas pero necesito que solo se pinte en las opciones que tienen hijos ya que al implementar las flechas pinta en todas las opciones

este es el codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Que sistema de templates estas usando?

Comment: Quizá lo que estés buscando sea un framework, como React.js.

Answer (score 0):

si usas un .blade.php puedes hacerlo con:

> `@if  //code @endif`

Pero html no admite la sentencia if.

Lo puedes ocultar o mostrar mediante javascript.

Comment: vale como podria declarar ese js?

Comment: ¿la extensión de tu fichero cuál es?